# Alternative for caption in AAAI template

Tags: floats, captions

I have a source that I need converted to the AAAI publication template, but the template itself clearly disallows the use of the `caption` environment. What would be the most straightforward and aesthetically similar way to convert the following example code of my source?

```
\begin{figure}[ht]
    \captionsetup{justification=centering}
    \includegraphics[scale=whatever]{path_to_image}
    \caption{My caption.}
    \label{fig:myfig}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: What do you mean with the `caption` **environment**? Are you talking about the `caption` _package_ or the `caption` _command_?

Comment: The AAAI template specifies that the entire `caption` **package** should not be used.

Comment: Answered the question, I can now tell the difference between a package, an environment and a command.

Answer (score 2):

And of course, I just realized the error in my ways. Just because one cannot use the **package** `caption` does not mean that they can't use the **command**  `caption`. `captionsetup` is unusable, but this is not a problem since the style file takes care of center justification itself. Marking this solved.